# Android deserialize exception

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization, illegalargumentexception

Okay, I have identical versions of my app, no code structure changed whatsoever.  I download the current market version of my app and I serialize some data and save it to the db.  I can reopen it in the app no problem.

The problem is, when I build a new version of my app, sign it, and upgrade my app, I get this exception when trying to deserialize:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type java.util.ArrayList, but got org.myApp.h.d
```

org.MyApp.h.d is actully org.MyApp.SingleFrame:

```
public final class SingleFrame implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int Position;
    public int FrameNumber;
    public String TimeStamp;
    public Map<Integer,String> MainDataMap;
    public Map<Integer,String> DataMap;

    public SingleFrame()
    {
    }
}
```

And here is its parent class  (the one that gets serialized and deserialized, just a collection of SingleFrame):

```
public class DataLog extends ArrayList<SingleFrame> implements Serializable
{   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DataLog ()
    {

    }
}
```

If I debug the app everything is fine.  The issue is when I build a version, save some data, then build a new version...updata the app, then try to open (deserialize) the old saved data.

Here is my proguard config:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```